# Set image in spinner to Gravity.Center

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-spinner

I have a spinner with images as items, the problem is that they're pushed to the left. A common problem with spinners i think. I've worked this out before but only with textviews, not images. How can I move the images to the center of the dropdown spinner menu?

Here's my custom spinner xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="50dp"
 android:orientation="horizontal"
 android:gravity="center"
 android:layout_gravity="center"
 >

    <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/icon"
     android:layout_width="35dp"
     android:layout_height="35dp"
     android:scaleType="fitStart"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:layout_gravity="center"
     android:src="@drawable/icon"
     />

</LinearLayout>
```

I've tried setting it to center in every possible way in xml (as you can see), but can't get it working..

I've tried this in java:

```
        ...
        @Override
        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            ((ImageView) getCustomView(position, convertView, parent)).setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        }
      ...
```

but i get an error on setGravity saying: The method setGravity(int) is undefined for the type ImageView

what to do ??

THanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that the LinearLayout's width is wrap_content, meaning that it will only be as wide as the image. Therefor it is centered. Try setting the layout_width="match_parent"